# Create Ogre3D 2.1 project

Tags: compiling, programming, c++

I have downloaded the Ogre3D 2.1 source, compiled and installed it without any issues. To my knowledge I have a working installation. The problem now is that none of the official project templates support 2.1 yet. I've tried getting it to work myself but the errors I get would indicate the code I'm working with simply is too outdated to work with 2.1.

Can some kind soul help me get started with a barebone Ogre3D 2.1 project?

Also, how do I fix it when I get the error for "#include "OgreOverlaySystem.h" not found", when it should be (for my system) "Overlay/OgreOverlaySystem.h"?

Answer (score 0):

I am having many problems with 2.1, compared with previous editions of OGRE as well.  The tutorials used to just plain work . . .

Anyway, to solved the specific error you state, find SdkTrays.h (mine is in `/usr/local/include/OGRE` and change the includes for the following to add `/Overlay`

```
#include "Overlay/OgreOverlay.h"
#include "Overlay/OgreOverlaySystem.h"
#include "Overlay/OgreOverlayManager.h"
#include "Overlay/OgreBorderPanelOverlayElement.h"
#include "Overlay/OgreTextAreaOverlayElement.h"
#include "Overlay/OgreFontManager.h"
```

I am on Linux mint but they are similar enough,